# How to treat global user/user data in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-hooks

I'm building a ReactJS project and I'm using something like this, to provide user data trough the app:

```
function Comp1() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (_user) {
    if (_user) {
      // User is signed in.
      // do some firestroe queryes to get all the user's data
      setUser(_user);
    } else {
      setUser({ exists: false });
    }
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <UserProvider.Provider value={{user, setUser}}>
        <Comp2 />
        <Comp3 />
      </UserProvider.Provider>

    </div>
  );
}

function Comp2(props) {
  const { user, setUser } = useContext(UserProvider);
  return (
    <div>
      {user.exists}
    </div>
  )
}

function Comp3(props) {
  const { user, setUser } = useContext(UserProvider);
  return (
    <div>
      {user.exists}
    </div>
  )
}

//User Provider

import React from 'react';

const UserProvider = React.createContext();
export default UserProvider;
```

So, in this case, Comp1 provides user data to Comp2 & Comp3. The only problem is that when the user state changes or the page loads, it creates an infinite loop. If I'm not using an useState for storing the user data, then when it changes, the components do not get re-rendered. I also tried to do something like this in the index.js file:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
  if (user) {
     ReactDOM.render(<Comp1 user={user} />, document.getElementById('root'));
  } else { 
     ReactDOM.render(<Comp1 user={{exists: false}} />, document.getElementById('root'));
  }
});
```

But this worked a bit weirdly sometimes, and it's kinda messy. What solutions are there? Thanks.

> Edit: I'm triening to do it in the wrong way? How should I provide all user data with only one firebase query?

Comment: You initialise user as `{}` so there's a good chance `user.exists` is not set on the first render.

Comment: That should not be a problem. Because my problem is, that it will be a changing variable, and I want to avoid an infinite loop.

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle so we can reproduce it?

Comment: You may need try to use redux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Issue:-

The issue for the loop to happen was due to the way Comp1 was written.
Any statement written within the `Comp1` functional component will get executed after ever change in prop or state. So in this case whenever `setUser` was called `Comp1` gets re-render and again it subscribes to the auth change listener which again executes setUser on receiving the data.

```
function Comp1() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (_user) {
    if (_user) {
      // User is signed in.
      // do some firestroe queryes to get all the user's data
      setUser(_user);
    } else {
      setUser({ exists: false });
    }
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <UserProvider.Provider value={{user, setUser}}>
        <Comp2 />
        <Comp3 />
      </UserProvider.Provider>

    </div>
  );
}
```

### Solution:-

You can use useEffect to make statements execute on `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUdate` and `componentWillUnmount` react's life cycles.

```
   // [] is passed as 2 args so that this effect will run once only on mount and unmount.

  useEffect(()=> {
    const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (_user) {
      if (_user) {
        // User is signed in.
        // do some firestroe queryes to get all the user's data
        setUser(_user);
      } else {
        setUser({ exists: false });
      }
    });

    // this method gets executed on component unmount.
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    }
  }, []);
```

I created a replica for the above case, you can check it running [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-plzzxe)

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using some state container for the application to easily manipulate with a user. The most common solution is to use `Redux`. With redux, you will be able to have a global state of your app. Generally, all user data stored in it. https://redux.js.org/
The other solution is to use `MobX` with simple store access. It doesn't use Flux pattern if you don't like it.
If you don't want to use a global store you can use `HOCs` to propagate your user data. Finally, you can use `Context` to React, but it is bad approach.

Let's, for example, choose the most popular representer of Flux architecture - Redux.

[image]

The first layer is the View layer. Here we will dispatch some action to change global, e.g user data.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux' 
import { logIn, logOut } from 'actions'

export default class Page extends React.Component {
  useEffect(() => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      logIn(user)
    } else {
      logOut()
   })
  }, [])

  render () {
    ...
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({
  logIn,
  logOut
}, dispatch)

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

The second layer are actions. Here we work we with our data, working with api, format state and so on. The main goal of actions is to create data to pass it to the reducer.

actions.js

```
export const logIn = user => dispatch => {
  // dispatch action to change global state    
  dispatch({
    type: 'LOG_IN',
    payload: user
  })
}

export const logOut = user => dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: 'LOG_OUT' })
}
```

The last thing is the reducers. The only goal of them is to change state. We subscribe here for some actions. Reducer always should be a pure function. State shouldn't be mutated, only overwritten.

appReducer.js

```
const initialState = {
 user: null
}

export default function appReducer (state = initialState, action) {
   const { type, payload } = action
   switch(type) {
     case 'LOG_IN':
       return {
          ...state,
          user: payload
       }
     case: 'LOG_OUT':
       return {
          ...state,
          user: null
       }
   }
}
```

Then, we can work with the global app state whenever we want.
To do it, we should use `react-redux` library and `Provider` HOC

```
const App = () =>
  <Provider store={store}>
     <Navigation /> 
  </Provider>
```

Now, we can have access to any stores inside any component though react-redux `connect` HOF. It works with React Context API inside of it.

```
const Page2 = ({ user }) => {
   //... manipulate with user
}

// this function gets all stores that you have in the Provider.
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  user: state.user
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Page2)
```

By the way, you should choose middleware to work with async code in redux. The most popular that is used in my example is `redux-thunk`.
More information you can find in the official documentation.
There you can find information about how to make initial store configuration

Comment: Woow... I'm nowhere this high level of understanding. Can you explain it in detail?

Comment: Ask if you have any questions. I suggest you create a simple todo project to understand the main concept

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean try to create a simple application where you will have such features as
1. Add item to the TODO ist
2. Remove item from the TODO list
3. Change item in the TODO list

With redux

Comment: If you don't want to use Redux, I would use the `useReducer` hook within React.

Comment: But I don't understand this :(

Comment: @BudaÖrs then it would make sense to create a small project first to try this out.

Comment: @LajosÁrpad I'm such a noob. This is why I'm giving the bounty. If someone can help me.

Comment: @BudaÖrs I am not experienced with ReactJS, but I think I know what your issue is.

Answer (score 3):

In `Comp1`, a new `onAuthStateChanged` observer is added to `firebase.Auth` on **every render**.

Put that statement in a `useEffect` like:

```
useEffect(() => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (_user) {
    if (_user) {
      // User is signed in.
      // do some firestroe queryes to get all the user's data
      setUser(_user);
    } else {
      setUser({ exists: false });
    }
  });
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this logic:

```
function Comp1() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (_user) {
    if (_user) {
      // User is signed in.
      // do some firestroe queryes to get all the user's data
      setUser(_user);
    } else {
      setUser({ exists: false });
    }
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <UserProvider.Provider value={{user, setUser}}>
        <Comp2 />
        <Comp3 />
      </UserProvider.Provider>

    </div>
  );
}
```

You are calling `setUser` in any case. Instead, you should check whether `user` is already set and if so, whether it matches `_user`. Set `user` to `_user` if and only if `_user` differs from `user`. The way it goes, `setUser` is triggered, which triggers `Comp2` and `Comp3` change, which triggers the event above which triggers `setUser`.